# ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir with { recursive: true }

Tags: node.js

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 with Node version 10.16.0.

```
const logDirPath = path.normalize('/var/log/ab');
if (!fs.existsSync(logDirPath)) {
    console.log('log path:', logDirPath);
    fs.mkdirSync(logDirPath, { recursive: true });
}
```

Results in:

```
log path: /var/log/ab
ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/log/ab'
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the `recursive` flag in your question. Fixed my `ENOENT` error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just figured it out. It was a permission error. Weird error message from node though.

Comment: @151291 Hey man. You need to allow your user (the user is the user you log into when you start up your computer) to be able to write to the directory. If you aren't doing anything important you could just do the lazy following: chmod -R 777 /your/directory/here (do NOT do this if you have sensitive stuff, this isn't very secure)